# Ensemble learning Python-Random Forest, SVM, KNN

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, random-forest, knn

I am trying to ensemble the classifiers Random forest, SVM and KNN.
Here to ensemble, I'm using the VotingClassifier with GridSearchCV.
The code is working fine if I try with the Logistic regression, Random Forest and Gaussian

```
clf11 = LogisticRegression(random_state=1)
clf12 = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=1)
clf13 = GaussianNB()
```

But I don't know what I was wrong in this below code cause I'm a beginner.
Here is my try to work with Random forest, KNN and SVM

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.ensemble import VotingClassifier

clf11 = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100,criterion="entropy")
clf12 = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=best_k)
clf13 = SVC(kernel='rbf', probability=True)
eclf1 = VotingClassifier(estimators=[('lr', clf11), ('rf', clf12), ('gnb', clf13)],voting='hard')

params = {'lr__C': [1.0, 100.0], 'rf__n_estimators': [20, 200]}

grid1 = GridSearchCV(estimator=eclf1, param_grid=params, cv=30)
grid1.fit(X_train,y_train)
grid1_predicted = grid1.predict(X_test)
print('Accuracy score : {}%'.format(accuracy_score(y_test,grid1_predicted)*100))
scores_dict['Logistic-Random-Gaussian'] = accuracy_score(y_test,grid1_predicted)*100
```

Whenever I run this I get

```
Invalid parameter estimator VotingClassifier.
```

These are the errors I'm getting.[image]
[image]

**Is it possible to ensemble Random Forest, svm and KNN?**

**Or else, is there any other way to do it?**

Comment: If you're getting an error, please [edit] your question to include the full error traceback

Comment: Please include the full error trace (edit your question accordingly).

Comment: I have updated the question. Could you  please check again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code posted is the following:

```
clf11 = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100,criterion="entropy")
clf12 = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=best_k)
clf13 = SVC(kernel='rbf', probability=True)
eclf1 = VotingClassifier(estimators=[('lr', clf11), ('rf', clf12), ('gnb', clf13)],voting='hard')

params = {'lr__C': [1.0, 100.0], 'rf__n_estimators': [20, 200]}
```

Here, you are using hiperparameters C for RandomForestClassifier, which will not work.

You must use hiperparameters that are valid for the classifiers that are being used. Maybe the names "lr", "rf" and "gnb" for the estimators show be replaced by other more adequate and then selecting hiperparameters valid for the different kind of classifiers

The following would work:

```
clf11 = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100,criterion="entropy")
clf12 = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=best_k)
clf13 = SVC(kernel='rbf', probability=True)
eclf1 = VotingClassifier(estimators=[('rf', clf11), ('knn', clf12), ('svc', clf13)],voting='hard')

params = {'svc__C': [1.0, 100.0], 'rf__n_estimators': [20, 200]}
```

Comment: What is the estimator param for knn???
And how can I improve the accuracy?

Comment: The hiperparameters for knn are here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html . Also, improving the accuracy is not straightforward, it depends on the problem

Comment: Maybe you can try using a StandardScaler() for preprocessing the features